# securityContext getVariables

Tags: security, authentication, navbar, display

How get userdata after login , please help

@RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, 
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false)String logout,Model model) {
         Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() ;
         String name = auth.getName() ;
         User us = user.findByUsername(name) ;
        String errorMessge = null;

```
    if(error != null) {
        errorMessge = "Username ou Password est incorrect !";
    }
    if(logout != null) {
        errorMessge = "hello" ;
       System.out.println(name) ;
       model.addAttribute("prenom", us.getNom());   

    }
    model.addAttribute("errorMessge", errorMessge); 
   model.addAttribute("prenom",name) ;


    return "admin.jsp" ;


}
```

*** display the name at my home page like this:

${prenom}

[Deconnexion](/logout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ModelAttribute
public void info(Model model) {
     UserPrincipal aut = (UserPrincipal)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() ;
    String name = aut.getUsername();
    User us = user.findByUsername(name) ;
    model.addAttribute("prenom",us.getPrenom()) ;

}
```

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, 
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false)String logout,Model model) {

```
    String errorMessge = null;

    if(error != null) {
        errorMessge = "Username ou Password est incorrect !";
    }
    if(logout != null) {
        errorMessge = "hello" ;

   //    model.addAttribute("prenom", us.getNom()); 

    }
 //   model.addAttribute("prenom", us.getNom());
    model.addAttribute("errorMessge", errorMessge);
```

//      model.addAttribute("prenom",name) ;

```
    return "admin.jsp" ;


}
```